# Anim Player is slow even with everything disabled

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I have a scene with models and geometry nodes to scatter objects on plane.

The models are animated, so when I want to play the anim playback to preview the animation, I get 6 fps while I set it to 30.

I've read many things online considering different options to optimize the viewport playback. I've tried them all (simplify, disabling objects, turning off modifiers, etc...) and nothing seems to affect the speed of the animation preview.

One thing to be noted, even when all objects are disabled, so with a blank viewport, I get 4-6 fps.

I have a Ryzen5900 and a RTX3090 so I don't think the computer is a problem.

How do I get the 30 fps ? Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Low FPS Blender(viewport)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163937/low-fps-blenderviewport) There are some tips for increasing performance.

Comment: But I can only repeat what I've said over and over again on many questions about viewport fps: the 3D viewport is not the right or best place to check the timing of your animations. There is a reason the _Frame Rate_ settings are in the _Output Properties_: they are mostly relevant if you render an animation directly as a video file where the fps are important for playback. But they do have a relevance before the output as well. Simulations need the fps settings to know how much time passes between frames to calculate the simulation speed based on real-time values.

Comment: If you want to check if your animation looks correctly from timing and flow etc., the best and recommended way to do this is go to the 3D viewport menu, _View_ > _Viewport Render Animation_. This renders the animation like you see it in the viewport (which can be from the camera or any other view you are looking at in that moment) and it renders a lot faster than a normal render of course. After that, press Ctrl+F11 to playback the viewport animation. This should play at the correct speed.